# Unable to browse synonyms in a Schema in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

In Oracle, I am user C(as you know schema and user are same). C was given READ ONLY access to both schemas A,B.
A has only tables. B has only synonyms pointing to A.
C is able to query tables, synonyms in A, B respectively using `select A.somename`, `select b.somename`.
But, in Oralce SQL Developer, C is unable to browse either tables or synonyms (on left pane, after going to Other users and selecting either A or B).

What could be the Root Cause.?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer will show you the objects in C that C owns - not show you the things that C has access to.

If you want to see the synonyms or objects you have SELECT privs on, go to the Other Users item, then open the tables or synonyms item in the tree.

But, you're NOT seeing them then either, but you know they are there?

Well, YOU know they are there, but database doesn't want you to know. We're querying the ALL_ views, which has security built into them. We're only showing you the contents of the ALL_ views.

If you were a privileged user, you'd have access to the DBA_ views, in which case you'd see every object in the database, and your synonyms would then be available.

There is an alternative, you can ask SQL Developer to treat synonyms for tables AS tables in the tree

[image]

We’re now not just querying TABLEs from ALL_OBJECTS, we’re now ALSO including SYNONYMS for any TABLEs.

Note: someone will have had to create a SYNONYM in your schema – this won’t pull in TABLES for PUBLIC SYNONYMS. Because…there are thousands of those, and no one wants to see all of that.

So let's do a quick scenario

```
create user a identified by oracle;

create user b identified by oracle;

create user c identified by oracle;

create user d identified by oracle;

grant connect, resource to a,b,c,d;
grant dba to d;

create table a.test(a int);
grant select on a.test to b;
create synonym b.a_test for a.test;
```

A won't be able to see B's synonym on the object in the A schema.
But
D will be able to - because it has access to the DBA_ views via that DBA role.

Looking via the D connection, browsing the Other Users, B, Synonyms -

[image]

If you look at the Statements Log, you can see the queries we're issuing to the Data Dictionary to list the objects. D is going through DBA_OBJECTS and DBA_SYNONYMS